# what does "npm add . " will do and how to revert back ? I mistakenly did that instead of git add

Tags: npm-install, revert

I did `npm add .` (there's a space after add and then a fullstop)
how do i revert back? i wanted to do `git add .`

Comment: isnt npm-add ???????

Comment: According [to the docs](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/commands/npm) there isn't an `npm add` command!

Comment: yes that aint , its `"npm add ."` like `"git add ."`

Comment: that command added a package , tried to add several packages but failed , only one package was added , i cant figure out which one as there are 100 of them

Comment: Did you see any output from this command? You could always just add the changes you want to git (not everything) and then do a git hard reset.

Comment: yes @phuzi output described as above in comment

Comment: git has nothing to do unless Karan compares with a prior version. the problem is on the local environment

Comment: this has nothing to do with git , mistakenly typed npm instead of git , yes it on local until i push

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most cleaner way is to:

1. Remove the package/s from the package.json, you might need to compare your local file with file in base.
2. Delete the node_modules folder
3. Run npm install again

Another alternative is to run npm remove  but if you did not get many new packages. Anyways my vote for the steps above.

Comment: i checked my package.json with the one on remote both are similar , but it showed that some packages were added .

Comment: ok. so you can even override the whole packages.json local from remote, save it and execute steps #2 and #3